# How to put a view on top of others

Tags: javascript, react-native, view

I want to build a searchable dropdown, I did a try but I was confronted by the problem in Image 1:

[image]

How can I put the flatlist of option in top of all things in my application ?

This is the render of the Searchable dropdown:

```
render = () => {
    return (
      <View
        keyboardShouldPersist="always"
        style={{ ...this.props.containerStyle }}
      >
        {this.renderSelectedItems()}
        {this.renderTextInput()}
        {/* {this.renderListType()} */}

        <View style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          <View
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              width: "100%",
              backgroundColor: "white",
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                zIndex: 1,
                width: "100%",
                backgroundColor: "white",
              }}
            >
              {this.renderListType()}
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Comment: you add the position to absolute without determine the height, try the height style to parent too

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.